# Mirroring Two Installations of Ubuntu

Tags: mirrors

I have a laptop and a desktop.  Ubuntu is on my laptop.  Is it possible to just mirror my entire Ubuntu installation (and all of the painstaking work I've done in configuring it to my liking) onto my desktop harddrive?

Furthermore, is there a way to keep these installations permanently in sync afterwords using DropBox or some similar service?  It's going to get old constantly keeping one machine up to speed with the other, as I'm constantly configuring things!

Answer (score 0):

Go for [Clonezilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonezilla), Linux/Ubuntu Does Not Have Problems With That Even If The Hardware Is Different, You Might Need To Edit Few Stuff And Tweaks, Yet Would Run Great.

Comment: Are you able to cloud sync using Clonezilla, or is it a one-time clone and then you have to keep manually syncing changes between the computers?

Comment: Its a 1 time sync, though you could use cron jobs with rsync after the new computer is running to keep things synced.